# Android animation why is it delayed by duration

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, duration

I have a simple translate animation in xml

anim.xml

```
<Translate
    xmlns:...
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

and I use it to slide a layout up from bottom of screen:

```
    View layoutStatus = activity.findViewById(R.id.layoutSettingsStatus);
    layoutStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up);
    layoutStatus.startAnimation(a);
```

But it doesn't start until 1500ms (or possibly longer) after this code is executed. When I change the anim duration from 1500 to 5000, it doesn't execute until 5 seconds after the code is executed. The duration property is working, it takes as long to translate as it does to start.

Its like android:duration is also applying to android:startOffset, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

From your snippets cant really say why that happens, I would need more code. But check this class [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), it can make your life and code easier in the future. Example of using it in your case :

```
layoutStatus.animate().translationY(toY).setDuration(1500);
// toY is float and takes coordinates on the screen
```

All you need in one line of code, as simple as it can get.
This class also contains all available methods like setStartDelay(), setInterpolator(), setListener() etc...
There are some differences between a TranslateAnimation and a ViewPropertyAnimation/ObjectAnimation which I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175429/objectanimator-vs-translateanimation/29187285#29187285).