# ViewGroup Animation Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-animation, viewgroup

I'm trying to do an easy translation animation in Android. The following doesn't work:

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup {
    ...
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -500);
    animation.setDuration(300);
    startAnimation(animation);
    ...
}
```

However, this works:

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup {
    ...
    animate().setDuration(300).translationYBy(-500);
    ...
}
```

I need the top version to work because I'm adding in more views that need to be animated at the same time and I'd like to use `TranslateAnimation`s inside an `AnimationSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Well after doing some research into both methods of animation I came up with the following:

```
List<Animator> animators = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = view.getChildAt(i);
    ObjectAnimator va = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(child, View.TRANSLATION_Y, child.getY() - 500);
    va.setDuration(300);
    animators.add(va);
}
```

Some explanation:

1. `TranslateAnimation`s are part of the older animation library included by Android. They don't actually change the underlying property values of the object as they animate it. I noticed if I performed other actions on the screen (like scrolling a ListView) as the animation performed, flashes of the animation were visible.
2. As of Honeycomb (Android 3.0), there is a newer way of animating things that changes the underlying property values themselves as it animates. It's called `ObjectAnimator`. Then in version 3.1, they introduced another class to help make `ObjectAnimator` even easier: `ViewPropertyAnimator`. The second method I was using is actually a shortcut to use `ViewPropertyAnimator`.
3. As I said in the question, I needed whatever solution I found to animate multiple things at once. Unfortunately `ViewPropertyAnimator` isn't capable of doing multiple animations at once. So I ended up using `ObjectAnimator`
4. Finally, because `ObjectAnimator` doesn't support translation by a certain value, I had to calculate the final Y positions of the views using their current Y values.

source: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html

Comment: What do you mean with ViewPropertyAnimator is not capable of doing multiple Animations at once?

Comment: Maybe this answer and the links to the Videos can help you understand the different animation APIs better : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175429/objectanimator-vs-translateanimation/29187285#29187285

Comment: I was unable to find any methods on ViewPropertyAnimator that allowed me to give a list of views and different values and animate all at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the actual question, more a suggestion of how to use ViewPropertyAnimator simultaneously with different Views and values. 
Write your own method and pass in the values you need as parameters for example (min implementation) :

```
private void animateView(View view, float transX, float transY, int duration) {

     view.animate().
         .translationXBy(transX)
         .translationYBy(transY)
         .duration(duration);
}
```

Add more parameters if you like. Interpolator, Scale, Rotate or Alpha values for example. Then use a loop or write another method to animate your views simultaneously. To be sure they animate all at the same time you could also add a small ms startDelay to the parameters to make sure all Animations are ready loaded before starting. Hope that helps.